# #nav-bar li:hover ul not working?

Tags: css

My following css selector `#nav-bar li:hover ul` should show the

```
  <li><a href="#">Marketing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
```

but its not showing here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/g9Rrn/1/

Comment: I'm not sure what you want it to do?  It looks like you want it to display the Marketing/advertising/media LI if they are hovering over Contact?

Comment: @BrianHoover yes i want to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you had:

```
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<li>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Marketing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
```

You already closed off the list element containing "Contact" before you contained the sub-list within it. What it should be:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Marketing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: This is true. Correct answer, I suppose